# popup auto redirect to undefined controller

Tags: html, codeigniter, model-view-controller, popup

i want to update data "barang" using pop up.
before the pop up goes down completely, the page redirect http://localhost/koperasi/index.php/cukl/undefined & show 
" The page you requested was not found" error.

....

this is my controller

```
public function ubahbarang(){

if ($this->input->post('ubahdatabarang')) {
  $id_barang=$this->input->post('id_barang');
  $id_jenis=$this->input->post('id_jenis');
  $nm_barang=$this->input->post('nm_barang');
  $stok=$this->input->post('stok');
  $hrg_beli=$this->input->post('hrg_beli');
  $hrg_jual=$this->input->post('hrg_jual');

  $this->barang->mengubah_barang($id_barang, $id_jenis, $nm_barang, $stok, $hrg_beli, $hrg_jual);
  redirect('cukl', 'refresh');
}
```

}

....

 this is my model

```
public function mengubah_barang($id_barang, $id_jenis, $nm_barang, $stok, $hrg_beli, $hrg_jual)
{
  $hasil = $this->db->query("UPDATE barang SET id_barang='$id_barang', id_jenis='$id_jenis', nm_barang='$nm_barang', stok='$stok',
                              hrg_beli='$hrg_beli', hrg_jual='$hrg_jual'");
  return $hasil;
}
```

...
this is table view which I use to update data using popups

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning">
                                    <h2>BARANG</h2><br>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID BARANG</th>
                                            <th>ID JENIS</th>
                                            <th>NAMA BARANG</th>
                                            <th class="text-right">STOK</th>
                                            <th class="text-right">HARGA BELI</th>
                                            <th class="text-right">HARGA JUAL</th>
                                            <th>ACTION</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <?php
                                        foreach($barang as $i): ?>
                                            <td><?=$i->id_barang;?></td>
                                            <td><?=$i->id_jenis;?></td>
                                            <td><?=$i->nm_barang;?></td>
                                            <td><?=$i->stok;?></td>
                                            <td><?=$i->hrg_beli;?></td>
                                            <td><?=$i->hrg_jual;?></td>
                                            <td style="text-align: center">
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_edit<?= $i->id_barang;?>" class="btn btn-success">
                  <i class="fa fa-pencil" color="white"></i>Ubah
                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>              
                                <?php endforeach ?>
                                </table>
```

and this is the popups code

(sorry i cant write it one the page :(( )
here is the pict 
[Opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O9q8.png)
[Closing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acad1.png)

---

*just in case the source code 

( https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LbKScF65ej2kT0iQfhU2egBwAGWGA7Ee )*

Comment: is this solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is right,but I think there is problem with routing.

You can try it by 301 redirect

```
redirect('/cukl', 'location', 301);
```

if still problem not solved please provide .htaccess and config/routes.php here.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `redirect('cukl', 'refresh');` to redirect

[Redirect](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect) goes in ways :-
 `redirect('control_name/method_name','refresh')`

Comment: still not working at all, i understand about redirect